# How to count total LOC in each object or function in JAVA?

Tags: java, object, methods, count, lines-of-code

I need to count the LOC of object or function. That is, for java, the number of methods in each object.

The other requirements were counting the physical LOC and logical LOC of a java code, I have done it.

My code is reading a .txt file with bufferreader and counting the code.

I counted the physical, logical, blank and comment lines. Now I need to count methods and object loc.

Expected output like that;

https://s8.postimg.org/cidz14y1h/Capture.png

Object name       # of Methods    Object LOC
XXX                5                 55
YYY                1                 9
ZZZ                3                 14

Can u help for this requirement?

```
public class HW2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String lineToRead = "";                                                 //will be used to read the lines from .txt file
    int totalNumberofCommentLines = 0;                                      //will be used to count comment lines
    int totalNumberofBlankLines = 0;                                        //will be used to count blank lines
    int totalNumberofLines = 0;                                             //will be used to count all lines
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F:\\HW-1\\4.txt"));
        try {
            while ((lineToRead = br.readLine()) != null) {
                totalNumberofLines++;
                if (lineToRead.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    totalNumberofBlankLines++;
                }
                if (lineToRead.startsWith("//")) {                          //if the line starts with single line comment 
                    totalNumberofCommentLines++;                            //if yes, count it
                } else if (lineToRead.startsWith("/*")) {                   //if the line starts with multiple line comment
                    totalNumberofCommentLines++;                            //if yes, look at the content of it
                    do {
                        if (lineToRead.trim().isEmpty()) {                  //if there is a blank line, count it as blank
                            totalNumberofBlankLines++;
                        }
                        else
                        {    totalNumberofCommentLines++;                    //else, count it as comment line
                            totalNumberofLines++;
                        }
                    } while (!(lineToRead = br.readLine()).endsWith("*/")); //count until see multiple comment line closure
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HW2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        br.close();                                                         //close the buffer reader to empty ram area
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Total Number of Physical Lines " + totalNumberofLines);
    System.out.println("Total Number of Comment Lines " + totalNumberofCommentLines);
    System.out.println("Total Number of Blank Lines " + (totalNumberofBlankLines));
    System.out.println("Total Number of Logical Lines " + (totalNumberofLines - ((totalNumberofBlankLines) + totalNumberofCommentLines)));
}
```

}

Comment: What if a line doesn't start with // but rather some whitespace followed by //? You will fail to catch this comment.

Comment: I have a JAVA coding standart which is written by me. It is not counted as a comment line if it is like u said. It is not an important case here.

Comment: So, how do you recognize a method (and object) in your file?

Comment: For the time being, I do not have a way to recognize it. According to my standart;
1- Physical LOC: Count the all lines of code
2- Logical LOC: Count the all lines of code without comment and blank lines
3- Method-Object LOC: ??? 

3 is not certain. If you have an advice to count, I can listen you. It is open to apply new standart to count.

Comment: For instance I can say that; "A method is a piece of code that's used to perform some specific functionality. It may or may not return a value. And it may/may not take parameters."

Comment: By recognizing methods, do you mean counting all method calls or something else? Or just counting the method bodies?

Comment: I understand it as counting all method calls, but method bodies can be counted too. https://s7.postimg.org/wff9flbvv/caption.png this link explained the requirement in detail.

Comment: Do u have a solution to solve the problem?

Comment: I'd probably go with regex but these kinds of parsers are all but trivial. Try to google lexical parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this snippet of Java code as an example of the ambiguity
encountered when determining SLOC:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) System.out.println("hello"); /* How many lines of code is this? */
```

In this example we have:

- 1 Physical Lines of Code (LOC)
- 2 Logical Line of Code (LLOC) (for statement and System.out.println statement)
- 1 comment line

Depending on the programmer and/or coding standards, the above "line of code" could be written on many separate lines:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 1)
{
   System.out.println("hello");
} /* Now how many lines of code is this? */
```

In this example we have:

- 4 Physical Lines of Code (LOC)
- 2 Logical Line of Code (LLOC)
- 1 comment line